# Updating Button Text in a ScrollView from Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, kivy

I'm writing a Kivy application that uses a ScrollView and sqlite database. I want to populate the button texts of the ScrollView buttons with data from the database once a button gets pressed in a previous screen. So far, I can not get it working.

I got my scrollview from here: [KIVY python - scroll view in a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749491/kivy-python-scroll-view-in-a-layout)

Update: I've been playing around with Clock inside the init method and I actually got it to populate the text under the condition that I press my submit button (located in a previous screen) within the time constraint set in `Clock.schedule_once`. I've tried using a trigger to achieve a similar effect without the time limit, but have not succeeded.

**Main.py**

```
p = Person()
dm = DataManager()

#...

class BasicProfileScreen(Screen):
container = ObjectProperty(None)

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(BasicProfileScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Clock.schedule_once(self.create_scrollview, 10)

def load_info(self, name):
    dm.read("Basic_Profile", name)

def create_scrollview(self, dt):
    base = ["element {}".format(i) for i in range(4)]
    n = 0
    layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=15, size_hint_y=None, padding=40)
    layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter("height"))
    while n < 2:
        layout.add_widget(Button(on_press=partial(self.nav_to_char_profile),
                                 text="Load from people.sqlite here", #<--the source of my frustration
                                 font_size=25,
                                 size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None),
                                 background_normal='normal.png',
                                 background_down='down.png'))
        n = n+1
    print(self.name_list)
    layout.add_widget(Button(on_press=partial(self.nav_to_char_profile), text="Back", font_size=25, size=(50, 50),
                             size_hint=(.50, None),
                             background_normal='normal.png',
                             background_down='down.png'))
    scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
    scrollview.add_widget(layout)
    self.container.add_widget(scrollview)

#...

)
```

## read and write from Database.py

```
def write(self, pid, nom, age, sex, height, weight):
    write_string="INSERT INTO Basic_Profile (id, name) "+"values (null, %s);" % ("'"+nom+"'")
    dm.execute([write_string])

def read(self, table, nom):
    l = []
    queries = ['SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE name = ' + '"' + nom + '"' + ';']
    for result in dm.execute(queries):
        for row in result[0]:
            l.append(row)
    return l[1]
```

Comment: Use just the minimum code necessary to produce your issue. Don't give us your entire file, that's not helpful.

Comment: I'll trim it down further, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is creating a trigger with Clock in the **init** method of BasicProfileScreen and a method that will call that trigger.

```
class BasicProfileScreen(Screen):

container = ObjectProperty(None)

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(BasicProfileScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self.create_scrollview)

def trigger(self):
    p.placeholder_list = some_new_list
    self.trigger()
```

and then adding the following where I want the trigger:

```
App.get_running_app().root.ids.BasicProfile.trigger()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call .fetchone() or .fetchall() on your select statement. It looks to me like .fetchall() would be appropriate in your specific case here. fetcall() returns a list, so this should work (untested)

```
def read(self, table, nom):
    l = []
    queries = ['SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE name = ' + '"' + nom + '"' + ';']
    for result in dm.execute(queries).fetchall():
        for row in result[0]:
            l.append(row)
    return l[1]
```

Otherwise check out the examples here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: The read and write work fine when I run  Database.py. It's when I try to get read() to work in Main.py that I have a problem.